# freeswtich docker container connectivity

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to run the docker container for freeswitch from the following URL

https://hub.docker.com/r/bettervoice/freeswitch-container/

When i issue the following command 
 CID=$(sudo docker run --name freeswitch -p 5060:5060/tcp -p 5060:5060/udp -p 5080:5080/tcp -p 5080:5080/udp -p 8021:8021/tcp -p 7443:7443/tcp -p 60535-65535:60535-65535/udp -v /home/ubuntu/freeswitch/conf:/usr/local/freeswitch/conf bettervoice/freeswitch-container:1.6.6)

After a while the following error is displayed

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint freeswitch (d805c283f72bc75752a0eb354195e4c7b606b54fed604d238df826261ceeeb43): Error starting userland proxy:.
ERRO[0509] error waiting for container: context canceled

Please help.